# Overide bootstrap base class attributes in less and meteor

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am trying to change the behaviour of a bootstrap class in my meteor code and have naively tried the following.

In my html I have added a class tb-sponsor to the div class list

```
<div class="col-md-8 column tb-sponsor">
      <h4> <strong>Papallo Kitchen & Joinery</strong></h4>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean enim diam, imperdiet et sem nec.
</div>
```

and in the tb.less file added

```
.tb-sponsor{
   .h4 {
      color: @tb-color;
   }
}
```

to try and change the color of the h4. Nothing happens. I can get things to happen if I use id=blah the #blah in the tb.less but not for classes. I'm obviously a missing something here. Any ideas please?

Comment: I don't use less but one thing that is off to me is h4 isn't class, try h4{}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the period (`.`) before `h4`