# How do LESS files work in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, less

I'm confused about how LESS files work. Can I just create a bunch of them and they're just magically included? How do I know they're being included in the right cascading order? What is the significance of the `.import.less` suffix? I have these files:

**client/stylesheets/variables.import.less**

```
@headline-font: 'Khula', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

**client/stylesheets/main.less**

```
h1 {
  font-family: @headline-font;
}
```

And Meteor does not like this:

```
While building the application:
client/stylesheets/main.less:14:16: Less compiler error: variable
@headline-font is undefined
```

Answer (score 5):

The default Less compiler for Meteor compiles every file with the .less extension into a single CSS file. Partial files with variables and mixins should not be compile into a single file, but imported into your project only.

The .import.less suffix prevents your files from being compiled into a CSS files, but can imported into your other Less files still.

See also: [Overide bootstrap base class attributes in less and meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143645/overide-bootstrap-base-class-attributes-in-less-and-meteor)

In your situation you will possible need the following line of code in your `main.less` file:

```
@import "client/stylesheets/variables.import.less"
```

Comment: Pardon the ignorant question, but why would I want to use `.import.less` suffix as opposed to just naming the file `variables.less`? I'm guessing since the order is not guaranteed, it's possible the LESS variables in that file might wind up being defined *after* the LESS file that uses them?

Comment: cause variables.less compiles into variables.css and variables.import.less not

Answer (score 1):

You need to include variables.import.less in main.less.

You may find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23527787/3624916